# Jupyter notebook won't import python modules, but python modules do run in terminal...?

Tags: python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, python-3.6

So I have python 2.7 and python 3.6 on my Mac.
Originally started with 2.7, then added 3.6
I use Jupyter notebook for work.

I CAN import python packages in Jupyter for python 2.7
but I CANNOT import python packages in Jupyter for python 3.6

HOWEVER
in terminal, I can import python packages for python 3.6

Why isn't Jupyter importing the packages? I pip3 installed a lot of stuff.

Comment: use pip2.7 instead of pip3

Comment: still doesn't work